# No Grounding Screw When Installing Ring Floodlight

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, grounding

**`I’m installing a Ring Floodlight at an existing light fixture, but there is no grounding screw to attach the green grounding wire from the Ring onto.

Is my best option to attach the Ring grounding wire to the mounting strap? Note that the mounting strap for the ring doesn’t have a separate place to attach a grounding screw and I don’t see a hole in the electrical box suitable for a grounding screw`**

Comment: Ground is nice to have for your safety, but only works if the box is grounded also.  If the box is not grounded, then where you attach(not to hot or or neutral) does not matter that much.  A grounded box should read 120v from hot and 0v from neutral.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back fo the box please?